Print PDF or XPS with WinRT Print API
I decided to modernize our product and replace the old printer code with WINRT printing. In order to send something to the printer you need to call
printDoc.AddPage(printElement);

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.printing.printdocument.addpages?view=windows-app-sdk-1.4
Note tht this method doesn't have overload that accept anything other than UIElement. This means if you want to print something with the new print API you need to obtain UIElement instance. XPS or PDF format are not supported.
To get a UIElement from a pdf file document, I used the WINRT and rasterized a pdf page to a BitmapSource like that
        private async Task<Microsoft.UI.Xaml.UIElement> GetPdfImage(uint pageNumber)
        {
            PdfPageRenderOptions options = new PdfPageRenderOptions();

            using PdfPage page = pdfDoc.GetPage(Math.Max(0, pageNumber - 1));

            InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            await page.RenderToStreamAsync(stream, options);
            BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();



            await src.SetSourceAsync(stream);

            Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image image = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image();
            image.Source = src;
            image.Stretch = Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.Stretch.None;
            image.Width = (int)page.Size.Width;
            return image;
        }

As you can guess the printed text looks awful and blurry. The only way to be able to print high quality text is to pass XAML that looks like this
    <Grid x:Name="PrintableArea">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>З
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="6*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel x:Name="Header" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="75"  Visibility="Collapsed">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/smallTile-sdk.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stretch="None"/>
                <RichTextBlock Foreground="Black"  FontSize="20" TextAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Segoe UI">
                    <Paragraph>Windows SDK Sample</Paragraph>
                </RichTextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
            <RichTextBlock Foreground="Black" x:Name="SdkTitle" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Segoe UI" >
                <Paragraph>PrintSample</Paragraph>
            </RichTextBlock>
        </StackPanel>

        <RichTextBlock Foreground="Black" x:Name="TextSelection" FontSize="18" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" OverflowContentTarget="{Binding ElementName=FirstLinkedContainer}"
            IsTextSelectionEnabled="True" TextAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Segoe UI" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="Collapsed"/>

        <RichTextBlock Foreground="Black" x:Name="TextContent" FontSize="18" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" OverflowContentTarget="{Binding ElementName=FirstLinkedContainer}"
            IsTextSelectionEnabled="True" TextAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Segoe UI" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Paragraph FontSize="32">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</Paragraph>
            <Paragraph></Paragraph>
            <Paragraph >...</Paragraph>
            <Paragraph></Paragraph>
            <Paragraph >...</Paragraph>
            <Paragraph></Paragraph>
            <Paragraph >...</Paragraph>
            <Paragraph></Paragraph>
            <Paragraph>... inceptos himenaeos.</Paragraph>
            <Paragraph></Paragraph>
            <Paragraph >...</Paragraph>
        </RichTextBlock>
        <RichTextBlockOverflow x:Name="FirstLinkedContainer" OverflowContentTarget="{Binding ElementName=ContinuationPageLinkedContainer}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <RichTextBlockOverflow x:Name="ContinuationPageLinkedContainer" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/print_1.png" x:Name="ScenarioImage" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10"/>

        <StackPanel x:Name="Footer" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontSize="16" TextAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Segoe UI">
                Copyright © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>

My question is - am I do something wrong or the only way to print PDF, XPS with WinRT print API is to convert it to XAML?

Yes, PrintDocument can only print UIElement currently. Could you please tell me what is your need, is it just to simply print a document? Do you need to edit the document in Winui3?

We have multiple apps that are similar to MS Office. They can read and write docx, excel files, pdf and etc. So far we used old windows API and convert them to XPS to send it to the printer. With WinRT I don't see how we can print them. Converting them to bitmap is not an option. The print looks awful.

What "old windows API" exactly did you use? Why is it working anymore?

We are currently using https://learn.microsoft.com/bg-bg/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/how-to-programmatically-print-xps-files?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8
I never said it is not working.

I think this is the only solution for Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Printing. It is recommended to use the win32 API you used before to print in winui3.

XPS and PDF are very different. You can create a non-XAML print document but it's not that easy. I've created some sample code here https://github.com/smourier/XpsPrintSamples The CustomPrintDocument demonstrates the custom non-XAML way and by default should output better quality prints.
